# Awk - Create a matching key- Take $4$3$2 from Line 01 and $4 from Line 07

Tags: unix, awk, key, match

**Desired Matching Key:** 
$4$3$2 from line 01 and $4 from line 07 of File1.txt

**Example:** In File1.txt $4=5000, $3=68, $2=89 in line 01 and $4=RT0429 or  RT0428 or RT0588  in line 07. 
The matching key in File2.txt is 50006889RT0428

**Issue:**
I am looking to create a match key from File1.txt and match against File2.txt first 14 characters.

**File1.txt (input)**

```
01  89  68  5000
02  83  11
04  83  9   02
03  83  00
06  83  00
07  83  11  RT0429
07  83  09  RT0428
07  88  10  RT0588
01  44  73  8800
02  44  73
04  44  73   02
03  44  73
06  44  73
07  44  11  RT0789
```

**File2.txt (input)**

```
50006889RT0428 CCARD /3010  /E     /C A87545457          /  //                ///11        ///

51002387 CCARD /3000  /E     /S N054896334IV          /  //                ///11        ///

51002390800666 CCARD /3000  /E     /S N0978898IV          /  //                ///11        ///
```

**File3 (Desired Output)**
Since only the first record from File1.txt has the matching key, the output would have the matching record from File2.txt

```
50006889RT0428 CCARD /3010  /E     /C A87545457          /  //                ///11        ///
```

**Script I am using**

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    out = "File3.txt"
    err = "File4.txt"
  }
  NR==FNR && NF {line[$1]=$0; next}
  function print_77_99() {
    if (key in line) 
      print "77", line[key] > out
    else {
      print "99", date > out
      printf "%s", lines >> err
    }
  }
  $1 == "01" {
    if (FNR > 1) print_77_99()
    key = $4 $3 $2
    lines = ""
  }
  {
    print > out
    lines = lines $0 "\n"
  }
  END {print_77_99()}
' File2.txt File1.txt
```

Comment: What part of this are you stuck on specifically?

Comment: You may at least reference your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058805/awk-combine-the-data-from-2-files-and-print-to-3rd-file-if-keys-matched) as it's only a small adaptation from it (just remove the print which are not the 77 and remove the 77 from the printf ...)

Comment: @EtanReisner I have updated the question and added the script I am using. I want to create a key that derives $4$3$2 from Line 01 and $4 from Line 07 from File1.txt and match against the first 14 characters of File2.txt. Currently my script is only matching the $4$3$2 from Line 01 from File1.txt only, not $4 from Line 07. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As per reading my comment it sounds unclear to me, here what I think would do:

(Code adapted from [Jonathan leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059657/3627607)

```
FNR == NR && ! /^[[:space:]]*$/ { 
    key = substr($1, 1, 8)
    a[key] = $0
    next
}
$1 == "01" { if (code != 0)
             {
                 if (code in a)
                 {
                     print a[code]
                     delete a[code]
                 }
             }
             code = $4$3$2
           }
END {
         if (code in a)
         {
             print a[code]
             delete a[code]
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using the script from Jonathan.  I have updated the question. But currently the script is taking only $4$3$2 form line 01 only, not $4 from Line 07.

Comment: @Etan Reisner I have updated the question and added the script I am using. I want to create a key that derives $4$3$2 from Line 01 and $4 from Line 07 from File1.txt and match against the first 14 characters of File2.txt. Currently my script is only matching the $4$3$2 from Line 01 from File1.txt only, not $4 from Line 07. Thanks,\