# awk search column from one file, if match print columns from both files

Tags: regex, awk, compare, match, multiple-columns

I'm trying to compare column 1 from file1 and column 3 from file 2, if they match then print the first column from file1 and the two first columns from file2.

here's a sample from each file:

file1

```
Cre01.g000100   
Cre01.g000500  
Cre01.g000650
```

file2

```
chromosome_1    71569  |655|Cre01.g000500|protein_coding|CODING|PAC:26902937|1|1)
chromosome_1    93952  |765|Cre01.g000650|protein_coding|CODING|PAC:26903448|11|1)
chromosome_1    99034  |1027|Cre01.g000100 |protein_coding|CODING|PAC:26903318|9|1)
```

desired output

```
Cre01.g000100  chromosome_1    99034        
Cre01.g000500  chromosome_1    71569   
Cre01.g000650  chromosome_1    93952
```

I've been looking at various threads that are somewhat similar, but I can't seem to get it to print the columns from both files. Here are some links that are somewhat related:

[awk compare 2 files, 2 fields different order in the file, print or merge match and non match lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117346/awk-compare-2-files-2-fields-different-order-in-the-file-print-or-merge-match?rq=1)

[Obtain patterns from a file, compare to a column of another file, print matching lines, using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470879/obtain-patterns-from-a-file-compare-to-a-column-of-another-file-print-matching)

[awk compare columns from two files, impute values of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592736/awk-compare-columns-from-two-files-impute-values-of-another-column)

[Obtain patterns in one file from another using ack or awk or better way than grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936962/obtain-patterns-in-one-file-from-another-using-ack-or-awk-or-better-way-than-gre)

[Awk - combine the data from 2 files and print to 3rd file if keys matched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058805/awk-combine-the-data-from-2-files-and-print-to-3rd-file-if-keys-matched)

I feel like I should have been able to figure it out based on these threads, but it's been two days that I've been trying different variations of the codes and I haven't gotten anywhere. 
Here is some code that I've tried using on my files:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$3]=$1;next;}{print $0 ($3 in a ? a[$3]:"NA")}' file1 file2

awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next} ($3 in a) {print $1 $2 a[$1]}' file1 file2

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next}{print a[$1] $0}' file1 file2
```

I know i have to create a temp matrix that contains the first column of file1 (or the 3rd column of file2) then compare it to the other file. If there is a match, then print first column from file1 and column 1 and column 2 from file 2.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F '[| ]+' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=$1 OFS $2; next}
       $1 in a{print $1, a[$1]}' file2 file1
Cre01.g000100   chromosome_1    99034
Cre01.g000500   chromosome_1    71569
Cre01.g000650   chromosome_1    93952
```

Answer (score 0):

Your middle attempt of the three is closest, but:

- You haven't specified the field delimiter is `|`.
- You don't assign to `a[$1]`.
- Your sample output is inconsistent with your desired output (the sample output shows column 1 from file 1 and column 1 from file 2; the desired output is reputedly column 1 from file 1 and columns 1 and 2 from file 2, though this interpretation depends on the interpretation of `$3` in file 2 being the name between two pipe symbols).

  Citing the question at the time this answer was created:

  > … compare column 1 from file1 and column 3 from file 2, if they match then print the first column from file1 and the two first columns from file2.
  >
  > ```
  > desired output
  > Cre01.g000100  chromosome_1    99034
  > Cre01.g000500  chromosome_1    71569
  > Cre01.g000650  chromosome_1    93952
  > ```
- We can observe that if `$3` in file 2 is equal to a value from file 1, then it is as easy to print `$3` as a saved value.

So, fixing this up:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=1; next } ($3 in a) { print $3, $1 }' file1 file2
```

The key change is the assignment to `a[$1]` (and the `-F'|'`); the rest is cosmetic and can be tweaked to suit your requirements (since the question is self-inconsistent, it is hard to give a better answer).